# I have a form where i want to add more input fields on button click in MVC View without scripting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie, i am trying to create a view where every time i click on add more link next to a Textbox, another text box appears. How do i do that? I searched the same question on this site but i could not find a solution.

Comment: Why do you want it done without scripting?

Comment: Because i do not know any scripting languages

Comment: If you can tell me how implement script it in mvc then its ok,but i have not idea how scripting works.

Comment: You may find you struggle with MVC without some scripting. It's not like ASP.Net which is based on a postback model. In MVC you'll probably find you need to do more client side code yourself. As MVC is more RESTful

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an array (`string[] Smth`)in your model. Then you have to make your "add more" link to submit your form to controller action that will add another element to this array and roundtrip back to view.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which illustrates how you could handle dynamic rows.